# Using a property as a default parameter value for a method in the same class

Tags: swift

In a Swift class, I want to use a property as a default parameter value for a method of the same class.

Here is my code :

```
class animal {
    var niceAnimal:Bool
    var numberOfLegs:Int

    init(numberOfLegs:Int,animalIsNice:Bool) {
        self.numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs
        self.niceAnimal = animalIsNice
    }

    func description(animalIsNice:Bool = niceAnimal,numberOfLegs:Int) {
        // I'll write my code here
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't use my *niceAnimal* property as a default function value, because it triggers me a compile-time error :

> 'animal.Type' does not have a member named 'niceAnimal'

**Am I doing something wrong ? Or is it impossible in Swift ?** If that's impossible, do you know why ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong.

The language specification only says that a default parameter should come before non-default parameters (p169), and that the default value is defined by an expression (p637).

It does not say what that expression is allowed to reference. It seems like it is not allowed to reference the instance on which you are calling the method, i.e., self, which seems like it would be necessary to reference self.niceAnimal.

As a workaround, you could define the default parameter as an optional with a default value of nil, and then set the actual value with an "if let" that references the member variable in the default case, like so:

```
 class animal {
     var niceAnimal: Bool
     var numberOfLegs: Int

     init(numberOfLegs: Int, animalIsNice: Bool) {
         self.numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs
         self.niceAnimal = animalIsNice
     }

     func description(numberOfLegs: Int, animalIsNice: Bool? = nil) {
       if let animalIsNice = animalIsNice ?? self.niceAnimal {
         // print
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As a developper, what do you think about this behavior ?

Comment: I'm not sure really. I think that default parameter values are a nice convenience, but that they can also lead to surprising and complex corner cases regarding when the default expression is evaluated. I know it gets messy in Python. So I can see the virtue of keeping it explicit and limited. I think the workaround is not so bad.

Comment: Yes. Consider: if the default value expression were evaluated in the context of the instance (i.e., with an ability to reference self), then it would be acting almost like a completely separate instance method that is called before the instance method you're trying to call. Can it access private members? superclass members? It's not an impossible but design but it probably conceals unintended surprises.

Comment: Note that there's no need to use `if let` here (doesn't even compile in Swift 3), as `niceAnimal` is non-optional, thus `??` will produce a non-optional. Just say `let animalIsNice = animalIsNice ?? self.niceAnimal`.

Answer (score 0):

I think for now you can only use literals and type properties as default arguments.

The best option would be to overload the method, and you can implement the shorter version by calling the full one. I only used a struct here to omit the initializer.

```
struct Animal {

    var niceAnimal: Bool
    var numberOfLegs: Int

    func description(#numberOfLegs: Int) {
        description(niceAnimal, numberOfLegs: numberOfLegs)
    }

    func description(animalIsNice: Bool, numberOfLegs: Int) {
        // do something
    }

}
```